# I can run the python file in pycharm, but not by using the cmd in Windows (message : no module named xxx)

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have this folder structure:

```
project:
|-the_package:
|  |-simulator.py
|  |-__init__.py
|-folder:
|  |-file1.py (contains: from the_package.simulator import xxx)
```

In cmd I type "python file1.py" and i get the following error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'the_package'.
Thanks for your help

Comment: You might have installed the package in the virtual environment set up by PyCharm. Just install the packages using CMD instead.

Comment: could someone  please help to this man to format code

Comment: Better, @dulajkulathunga?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the command you are using, I assume you are running the command inside the `folder` directory. From there, there is indeed no module or package called `the_package`.

Instead try moving up a directory, so that you are calling from inside `project`, and run it as `python folder/file1.py`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I better clarify my problem below

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am new in python, I would like to correct my question.

I have this structure: 
python_package
  module1
   file1.py:
   **init**.py
  module2
      file2.py
    **init**.py
My file1.py contains some parameters which I want to import in file2.py.
In file2 I wrote : *from module1.file1 import some_parameters* 
It is working with Pycharm but not in command line (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1'), why is that ?

Thanks Again

Comment: add a blank file `__init__.py` file inside every folder starting from python package

Comment: within the python_package folder as well, since you're calling `from module1.file1 import param1`

Answer (score 0):

1. I recommend running `python -m folder.file1.py` inside `project` folder. Sometimes, `import` in python is confusing. As far as I know, there is no simple way to solve your case of running inside folder (sibling import). Here is another similar SO question about this issue. [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)
2. PyCharm did some works behind the scene and that is why sometimes there is different behavior. In your case, try unticking "Add content roots to PYTHONPATH" of configuration and then you will get the same error. About PyCharm configuration: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html